# How to tell if I'm connected to an Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL cluster?

Tags: aws, aurora

I've created few different instances, one instance is of Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL and other instances are of PostgreSQL, MySQL etc. How do I find our the Postgres instance is running within an AWS Aurora cluster or not, from CLI? When I say from CLI this means terminal not AWS CLI.

Comment: `select version() ;` should tell you a few things about the instance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking for the existence of the **rdsadmin** database (to be precise, this database exists for any RDS instance, not just an Aurora-based one).   One way to check would be to use the **psql** command-line tool to output a list of databases.  Just replace [AuroraClusterEndpoint] and [UserName] in the following

***psql -h [AuroraClusterEndpoint] -U [UserName] --password -l***

[image: Sample output from psql - listing all databases]

Of course, this assumes you haven't created a database named rdsadmin on your non-RDS Postgres cluster.

You could also use the **SHOW ALL** command within psql to check for the existence of an RDS-based run-time parameter:

[image]

With both solutions, just use whatever scripting tool you're comfortable with (Powershell, Bash, etc...) if you want to programmatically parse out the results